# How to get description for Google API nearbysearch items

Tags: api, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web app for client requirement in that i am using Google API for finding nearby place

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=.....

I was able to get all the required details. Name, rating, etc but only description is missing. will i be able to get it from anywhere,  i tried

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=...

but not getting required result only country or place is getting here not restaurant or venue description. Please help me to get details for each item in nearby search result. Or any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of both **[Google Places API Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)** and **[Google Places API Text Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests)**, **description** property is not included in the returned results. You could rather file for a **Feature Request** to include **description** to each returned places in the results here at **[Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)**.

> Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and
>   feature requests during product development. It is available outside
>   of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to
>   collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

You can learn more about Issue Tracker through this **[link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)**.

I would also like to suggest to read **[Google Places API Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)**. It returns more comprehensive information about the indicated place such as its complete address, phone number, user rating and reviews.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. But i am not able to get specific details description for near by places, when i try issue tracker its getting blank